# Autofac 2.6.1 AOP Interception

Tags: logging, aop, autofac, interception

Folks,
Has anyone successfully used AOP Interception with recent versions of Autofac. Most earlier examples I can find of Interception rely on AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2 which now seems out of date.
Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2 is working and yes there is not much activity in that space. There are couple of specific issues which are open but they are specific.

http://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=359

http://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=355

Did you faced any specific problems while using interception with 2.6.1 ?